# How to reference the imageid from a docker build using docker/build-push-action@v2?

Tags: github-actions

I want to reference the imageid from the docker build using docker/build-push-action@v2
action in my next github action step when deploying to kubernetes using a Helm chart.  For now I just want to echo it out in the next part of my github action step.

This is the github documentation link for [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action)

The following is a snippet of my github action worfklow:

```
      - name: Build and push Docker images
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - name: Print my docker imageid in a separate step
        run: echo "imageid"
```

The following is the output from the docker build-push-action:

```
#15 pushing layer 54b5e2b53cf2 4.9s done
#15 DONE 4.9s
ImageID
  sha256:043e18541***e07db034bd94c5423cbd8f6ea8f045c5c8ccdd97b9254c4b5f11
Digest
  sha256:043e18541***e07db034bd94c5423cbd8f6ea8f045c5c8ccdd97b9254c4b5f11
Metadata
  {
    "containerimage.digest": "sha256:043e18541***e07db034bd94c5423cbd8f6ea8f045c5c8ccdd97b9254c4b5f11"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the `imageId` as described in the [output](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#outputs) section of the doc. Just add an id at your current job just for reference, as example:

```
  - name: Build and push Docker images
    id: docker_build
    uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
    with:
      context: .
      push: true
      tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
      labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

  - name: Print my docker imageid in a separate step
    run: echo "imageid ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.imageid }}"
```

Comment: I had overlooked the "id" part before.  Thank you Matteo.

Comment: I am a bit confused why the imageid is produced sometimes in the docker build and sometimes only the digest is present in the output.